# How can I use multiple objects in ng-style for a single element in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two `ng-style` objects in my controller.

```
$scope.leftpadding = {
    paddingLeft : '7px'
}

$scope.toppadding = {
    paddingTop : '7px'
}
```

I want to use both these objects in `ng-style` like

```
<h5 ng-style="toppadding leftpadding">
```

Is not working. as neither of the objects are being applied in style.

It can't be like

```
$scope.style = {
  paddingLeft : '7px',
  paddingTop : '7px'
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a common method in scope

```
$scope.margeStyleObj = function(objectList) {
    var obj = {};
    objectList.forEach(function(x) {
      for (var i in x)
        obj[i] = x[i];
    });
    return obj;
  }
```

Then call from html

```
<h5 ng-style="margeStyleObj([toppadding,leftpadding])">
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/7xps3300/3/)**</kbd>

You can also use **[angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)**

Like this

```
  $scope.margeStyleObj = function(objectList) {
    var obj = {};
    objectList.forEach(function(x) {
        angular.extend(obj,x);
    });
    return obj;
  }
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/7xps3300/4/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you can use `ngStyle` in that way. Try this:

```
ng-style="{'padding-top': paddingTop, 'padding-bottom': paddingBottom}"
```

And have `$scope.paddingTop` to have whatever value you want for `padding-top`, `padding-bottom`.

Comment: This will make my code huge. It is just an example I put in the question, it may potentially have 5-6 styles for an element.

Comment: yeah i understand that, let me dig in a little.

Comment: First object is applied, second is not

Comment: do you have bottompadding defined in the controller, in your question it is left padding...

Comment: i am using `ng-style="[toppadding, leftpadding]"`

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe check my answer

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe, doesn't look like it. They have the array support for ngClass but not ngStyle.

Comment: @TarunDugar i was going to say this. Are you saitam's fan ?

Comment: fan would be an understatement! ;)